# How to split the 8 bit input into two 4 bit data

Tags: vhdl

I'm writing a code for QPSK modulation in VHDL. I need to split the 8 bit input  data into odd and even bits and each bit is replicated How can i do it.

for example if my input is 11001001 then  odd and even bits are odd= 1010  even =1001 my output should be like odd= 11001100 and even is 11000011

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're question is not answerable - you have provided no code. You need to write an [MCVE] with a clear indication of the step that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Your selection/expansion permutations can be done in various ways. Here's [one way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l0z8.jpg). Note you haven't provided any information about types nor endian-ness which can affect the definition of even and and odd from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator '&':

```
dbl_odds  <=  v(7) & v(7) & v(5) & v(5) & v(3) & v(3) & v(1) & v(1);
dbl_evens <=  v(6) & v(6) & v(4) & v(4) & v(2) & v(2) & v(0) & v(0);
```

Comment: *indexed_name ::= prefix **(** expression { , expression } **)***  where those are parentheses and not square brackets.

Comment: Ooops been doing nothing but Verilog in the last two months!